# Floating Every Other Season Right

Tags: php, html, smarty

Hay everyone need a bit of help because i'm new to coding.

How can i get every other season to float right for example.

Season 1
Episode 1

then float season 2 right

Season 2
Episode 1

and the same for season 4, 6, 8 you get my drift.

```
<ul class="episodes">
   <div class="tv_container"> 
  {foreach from=$episodes key=id item=val name=episode_loop}
  {if $val.episode eq 1}
      <h2>Season {$val.season}</h2>
  {/if}
<h5 class="episode_item">
{if $global_settings.seo_links}
   <a class="link" href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.show}/{$val.perma}/season/{$val.season}/episode/{$val.episode}" title="{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}">Episode {$val.episode}{if $val.episodetitle} <span class="tv_episode_name"> - {$val.episodetitle}</span>{/if}</a>
{else}
   <a class="link" href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=episode&perma={$val.perma}&season={$val.season}&episode={$val.episode}" title="{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}">{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}   </a>
{/if}
</h5>
</li>
   {if $smarty.foreach.episode_loop.iteration % 4 eq 0}<div class="clear"></div>{/if}
{/foreach}
</div>
</ul>
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reworked your HTML a little bit, but you should be able to get it to work using this.

```
<ul class="seasons">
    {foreach from=$episodes key=id item=val name=episode_loop}
        {if !isset($lastSeason)}
            <ul class="episodes">
            <li>
                <h2>Season {$val.season}</h2>
        {elseif $lastSeason != $val.season}
            </ul>
            <ul class="episodes" style="float: right;">
            <li>
                <h2>Season {$val.season}</h2>
        {/if}
                <div class="tv_container"> 
                    <h5 class="episode_item">
                    {if $global_settings.seo_links}
                        <a class="link" href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.show}/{$val.perma}/season/{$val.season}/episode/{$val.episode}" title="{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}">Episode {$val.episode}{if $val.episodetitle} <span class="tv_episode_name"> - {$val.episodetitle}</span>{/if}</a>
                    {else}
                        <a class="link" href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=episode&perma={$val.perma}&season={$val.season}&episode={$val.episode}" title="{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}">{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}   </a>
                    {/if}
                    </h5>    
                </div>
            </li>
            {assign var=lastSeason value=$val.season}
    {/foreach}
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, I believe;

```
<ul class="episodes">
    <div class="tv_container"> 
        {foreach from=$episodes key=id item=val name=episode_loop}
            {if $val.episode eq 1}
                <h2>Season {$val.season}</h2>
            {/if}
            <h5 class="episode_item" {if $smarty.foreach.episode_loop.iteration % 2 eq 0}style="float:right;"{/if}>
                {if $global_settings.seo_links}
                    <a class="link" href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.show}/{$val.perma}/season/{$val.season}/episode/{$val.episode}" title="{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}">Episode {$val.episode}{if $val.episodetitle} <span class="tv_episode_name"> - {$val.episodetitle}</span>{/if}</a>
                {else}
                    <a class="link" href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=episode&perma={$val.perma}&season={$val.season}&episode={$val.episode}" title="{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}">{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}   </a>
                {/if}
            </h5>
            {if $smarty.foreach.episode_loop.iteration % 2 eq 1}<div class="clear"></div>{/if}
        {/foreach}
    </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: That just makes every other episode to float right any other ideas?.

Comment: Rework your array so that the episodes are grouped together by season before you get in to the template and then have a nested loop. First loop runs through seasons, second loop runs through episodes, float accordingly.